# maximum value of a substring in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
var arr = [
{"subId":"dfsfsdfsdfSUB201800099","userID":"dfsfsdfsdf"},
{"subId":"dfsfsdfsdfSUB201800139","userID":"dfsfsdfsdf"},
{"subId":"dfsfsdfsdfSUB201700649","userID":"dfsfsdfsdf"}, 
{},
{}............]
```

I have an array , I want to find the value of subId which contains "dfsfsdfsdfSUB2017" and is the maximum 00139 in this example.

Comment: can please provide what you had already try

Comment: tried using _lodash.maxBy

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```js
let someArray = [{
  "subId": "dfsfsdfsdfSUB201800099",
  "userID": "dfsfsdfsdf"
}, {
  "subId": "dfsfsdfsdfSUB201800139",
  "userID": "dfsfsdfsdf"
}, {
  "subId": "dfsfsdfsdfSUB201700649",
  "userID": "dfsfsdfsdf"
}]

let ids = someArray.map(item => parseInt(item.subId.split('dfsfsdfsdfSUB')[1]))

console.log(Math.max(...ids))
```

Comment: `dfsfsdfsdfSUB2017 != dfsfsdfsdfSUB`!!! and also where is the checking for *contains*?

Comment: that would be good safety check before trying to split, I agree but I went the assumption the dfsfsdfsdfSUB will be there in all subId, so I didn't check, But I agree it is always good to check.

Comment: Then the map would something like blow

 `let ids = someArray.map(item => parseInt(item.subId.includes('dfsfsdfsdfSUB')&& item.subId.split('dfsfsdfsdfSUB')[1]))`